# Tap on tabBarItem to Present a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, action, uitabbaritem

I have a custom command here to scrollToTop if any tabBar item is pressed twice. but now i want to add a function to a specific tabBaritem ( tag 3 lets say....)

## How do i combine what i have now:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let viewControllers = viewControllers else { return false }
        if viewController == viewControllers[selectedIndex] {
            if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController {
                guard let topController = nav.viewControllers.last else { return true }
                if !topController.isScrolledToTop {
                    topController.scrollToTop()
                    return false
                } else {
                    nav.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}
extension UIViewController {
    func scrollToTop() {
        func scrollToTop(view: UIView?) {
            guard let view = view else { return }

            switch view {
            case let scrollView as UIScrollView:
                if scrollView.scrollsToTop == true {
                    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
                    return
                }
            default:
                break
            }

            for subView in view.subviews {
                scrollToTop(view: subView)
            }
        }

        scrollToTop(view: view)
    }

    var isScrolledToTop: Bool {
        if self is UITableViewController {
            return (self as! UITableViewController).tableView.contentOffset.y == 0
        }
        for subView in view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = subView as? UIScrollView {
                return (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
            }
        }
        return true
}
}
```

## With this(so i can make the specific action to a specific tabBarItem):

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0 {
        // present your first view controller
    }
    else if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1 {
        // present your second view controller
    }
    else if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2 {
        // present your third view controller
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Use tap gesture recognizer.

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        tap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyTabBarController.twiceTapped(sender:)))
        tabBar.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func twiceTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // handle here
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think you understood. Right now i have a function that adresses all tabBarItems.But i want in addition to that function.to tell tabbarItem at index 3 to present a viewController when tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if i get this right : you want to do something based on the item(first, second, etc) selected in the tab bar. If so, i think you can use this based on the tag of your item(if you set the delegate) :

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    switch item.tag {
    case 1:
        // your code
    default:
        // your code
    }
}
```

And dont forget to set the tag of each one of your itens in the tab bar.

Comment: Yes i know this but i cant use both should select and did select functions im asking for help to kinda combine both so will get both functionalities